# Equivalent of "binary-size(N)" pattern matching over a bitstring of Elixir/Erlang, in Haskell

Tags: haskell, binary, binary-data

I can do this in Elixir or Erlang:

```
s = "my binary string"
<<head::binary-size(6), _rest::binary>> = s     
head ===> "my bin"


s2 = <<18, 22, 13, 44, 52, 99>>                  
<<head2::binary-size(4), _rest::binary>> = s2
head2 ===> <<18, 22, 13, 44>>
```

That is, `head` and `head2` are the variables with the results I'm interested in.

I'm familiar with the `binary` library  of Haskell. I haven't found the equivalent functionality in it - https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.10.0.0/docs/Data-Binary-Get.html#t:Get

Is there a way to do the same thing in Haskell, specifically in `binary` library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent feature in Haskell `binary` is [the `getByteString` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.10.0.0/docs/Data-Binary-Get.html#v:getByteString).

```
getByteString :: Int -> Get ByteString

getByteString 6 :: Get ByteString

example = runGet (getByteString 6) "my binary string" :: ByteString
```

Use do-notation to compose `Get` parsers. There is also `getRemainingLazyByteString` to get the rest of a bytestring, but be aware that although it is useful for Elixir/Erlang-style parsing, in Haskell composition of parsers subsumes most of it:

```
getThreeBS :: Get (ByteString, ByteString, ByteString)
getThreeBS = do
  x <- getByteString 2
  y <- getByteString 3
  z <- getRemainingLazyByteString
  return (x, y, z)

example1 = runGet getThreeBS "Hello World!"  -- ("He", "llo", " World!")
```

Another relevant function is `Control.Monad.replicateM`:

```
replicateM :: Int -> Get a -> Get [a]

example2 = runGet (replicateM 5 getWord8) (ByteString.pack [18, 22, 13, 44, 52, 99]) :: [Word8]
```